# Typo3 pidInRootline on specific ID

Tags: typo3, typoscript

i often use conditions with `[PIDinRootline = {$any-id}]` which checks if the given ID is inside the current rootline.
Now i need something similar for a given PID.
I thought about a ViewHelper that accepts a PID and an ID as arguments and builds a rootline for PID and checks against ID. Is there anything already available or did anybody do something like that in the past?

best regards,
simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `EXT:vhs`, it this should work:

```
<f:if condition="{v:page.rootline(pageUid: X.uid) -> v:iterator.filter(propertyName: 'uid', filter: Y.uid)}">
    <f:then>X is child page of Y</f:then>
    <f:else>X is not a child page of Y</f:else>
</f:if>
```

It calculates the root line of the child page `X` (which is an array of page records), then filters out all elements having an uid that is different from the uid of `Y`, and checks whether the result is empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
<v:condition.page.isChildPage then="[mixed]" else="[mixed]" pageUid="123" respectSiteRoot="1">
    <!-- tag content - may be ignored! -->
</v:condition.page.isChildPage>
```

https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Condition/Page/IsChildPageViewHelper.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer. With that one i can check if page X is a child page but i cannot check if page X is a child page of page Y.

Comment: I also tried this without success:                                                 `<v:condition.iterator.contains needle="UID1" haystack="{v:page.rootline(pageUid: UID2) -> v:iterator.extract(key: 'uid')}">
                                                    <div style="display:none">nutrition</div>
                                                </v:condition.iterator.contains>`